# Informix database issue: Changing the datatype format

Tags: vba, informix

I am using informix database for storing the data. Everything is storing correctly. But I need to change the datatype format of the **Timecol**. Now the **TimeCol** format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:0000`. While storing the data,the **Timecol** is coming like that. I want to change the `0000` from the **Timecol**. Is it possible to change the datatype format of **Timecol** in informix database?

Comment: but why VBA tag for this question??

Comment: iam using vba  to link informix with my software

Comment: Observations: (1) The colon after the `ss` value should be a dot `.`. (2) You have not stated what the type of the column in the table is — presumably DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(4) since there are, it appears, 4 decimal places of sub-second accuracy, but it could be that the column is DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND yet you retrieve into a variable equivalent to DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(4).  Or it could be that you're creating a timestamp in the server but you don't have `USEOSTIME` set in the ONCONFIG file, which leads to CURRENT not supporting fractional seconds.  Or it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you cannot change it but adjust it with extend.

for example

```
select extend(current,year to fraction(2)) from sysmaster:sysdual
```